# C# Ghostscript Wrapper

Tags: c#, wrapper, ghostscript

Has anyone encountered a nice wrapper for GhostScript in C#.
My specific use is to take postscript and turn it into a pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open-source [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) has a namespace for using GhostScript.  Even if you can't directly use it, you can probably graft whatever you need out of the source.

Comment: I can not find such namespace in pdfsharp, not even in the repository at the moment of post.

Comment: @Razvan, if you need Ghostscript wrapper, take a look at: http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com

Answer (score 14):

Matthew Ephraim has created a pretty simple C# wrapper called GhostScriptSharp that uses P/Invoke to access the unmanaged Ghostscript DLL in your C# application:

http://mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/06/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ghostscript/

Comment: Old question/answer, but still relevant: As-is the GhostscriptSharp wrapper only provides access to a couple of functions *for generating thumbnails from PDFs*. It would not cover the question asked here, which was "converting postscript to a PDF", without adding code to it.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, there's also [Gouda Ghostscript wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/gouda/). You can also perform some ghostscript operations indirectly through imagemagick/graphicsmagick (they delegate to GS), so using a .NET library like [GraphicsMagick.NET](https://graphicsmagick.codeplex.com/) might be a good approach for you.

EDIT:

I just stumbled upon [Ghostscript.NET](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/) as well. It claims to be

> ...the most completed managed wrapper library around the native Ghostscript library (32-bit & 64-bit), an interpreter for the PostScript language, PDF, related software and documentation

and among other features, allows you to run multiple Ghostscript instances simultaneously within a single process.